# CRON Expressions every hour at specific times

Tags: apex, batch, scheduled-apex, cron

Is it possible to run CRON job every hour at a specific time at that hour? I only ask because I want to spread out my scheduled batch classes throughout the hour to avoid maxing out the flex queue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The UI only allows on-the-hour scheduling, but if you use System.scheduleJob, you can specify the minute and second as well. Be aware that jobs will still only run when resources are available, but this extra flexibility should provide you with the desired "staggering" of jobs.

Comment: My issue right now is that all the jobs start right at the beginning of the new hour. This should definitely do the trick for avoiding the flex queue limits